# How to dynamically show text that's in a header box on multiple line boxes in real time on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have an HTML header box like so

```
<textarea name="order[header_comments]"></textarea>
```

and then I have line comment boxes like so:

```
<textarea name="line_comments[0][line_comments]"></textarea>
<textarea name="line_comments[1][line_comments]"></textarea>
...
<textarea name="line_comments[n][line_comments]"></textarea>
```

Line boxes may have some text in them already.

**What I want to do is this:**

As I type anything in the header box, I want it to be immediately pre-pended to all the line comment boxes. That is all line comment boxes need to at all times have this, even if line boxes are edited, before, or after the header box is filled in:

```
{real-time header text}{EOL}{any text that was there already}
```

I assume that if I edit any text in the line boxes, it must not touch the header text (otherwise things will get messed up).

**How do I do this?**

I can add `id` for `class` to the textarea tags as needed. I am not sure which technique to use or how to begin.

My started code:

```html
<textarea name="order[header_comments]" placeholder="header box"></textarea>

<textarea name="line_comments[0][line_comments]"></textarea>
<textarea name="line_comments[1][line_comments]">some existing text</textarea>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing anything yet?

Comment: I am trying to visualize how to separate header text and line text.  I could use a naive approach of just copying header text to the line text as-I-type.  But then, say I go and edit a line box, (what if I delete all text out of there?) and then go back to the header text.  The behavior of what happens when I edit the header box is undefined.  I guess I need a way to have un-editable header text in each line box.  But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
var prevPrincipalVal = "";
$("#principal").keyup(function(){
    var principalVal = $(this).val();
    $(".other").each(function(){
         $(this).val($(this).val().replace(new RegExp("^" + prevPrincipalVal + "\n*"), principalVal + "\n"));
    })
    prevPrincipalVal = principalVal;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="principal"></textarea>
<textarea class="other">Custom 1</textarea>
<textarea class="other">Custom 2</textarea>
<textarea class="other">Custom 3</textarea>
```

The basic idea is to save the previous value of the principal `<textarea>` and replace the previous value with the new one in each of the other `<textarea>`s. These needs perfecting, you'll have to escape all special regex character from the text of the principal `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is close to what you're describing (with the assumption that the line comments should be unmodifiable).

```js
var previousLength = 0;
$("#headerBox").on('keyup', function() {
  var headerVal = $("#headerBox").val();
  $('.commentBox').each(function(){ 
       this.value = headerVal + this.value.substring(previousLength, this.value.length);
  });
  previousLength = headerVal.length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="headerBox" name="order[header_comments]" placeholder="header box"></textarea>

<textarea readonly class="commentBox" name="line_comments[0][line_comments]"></textarea>
<textarea readonly class="commentBox" name="line_comments[1][line_comments]">some existing text</textarea>
```

EDIT: This demonstrates "protecting" the prepended header content in the line comments. Attempts to modify the header portion of the line comment will immediately be reverted.  It's not perfect, I'm sure some cases aren't accounted for, but hopefully a helpful starting point.

```js
var previousLength = 0;
$("#headerBox").on('keyup', function() {
  var headerVal = $("#headerBox").val();
  $('.commentBox').each(function(){ 
    this.value = headerVal + this.value.substring(previousLength, this.value.length);
  });
  previousLength = headerVal.length;
});

var beforeChange = "";
$('.commentBox').on('keydown', function() {
  beforeChange = this.value;  
});

$('.commentBox').on('keyup', function() {  
  var headerVal = $("#headerBox").val();
  if (!this.value.startsWith(headerVal)){
    this.value = beforeChange;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="headerBox" name="order[header_comments]" placeholder="header box"></textarea>

<textarea class="commentBox" name="line_comments[0][line_comments]"></textarea>
<textarea class="commentBox" name="line_comments[1][line_comments]">some existing text</textarea>
```

Comment: +1 Nice approach. I've made this more complicated then it has to be by storing the previous value and using a regex to replace it with the new one. The only thing needed to be stored is the length. Did not think of that.

Comment: I do like this approach.  One thing though is line comments are locked and I do need to edit them.  Unlocking them works, but in some cases can blindly replace text from beginning of the string, when header is edited again

Comment: I noticed a comment you made elsewhere about the line comments being unmodifiable and used that as an assumption for my solution.  I see now that you were referring only to the prepended content at the beginning of the line comments being unmodifiable, which adds some complexity.  You could potentially track the value of each line comment, compare any changes made to determine if the prepended content is being modified and set it back to the previous value in that case.  If this is handled well, my solution should be compatible with line comment edits to the non-prepended text.

Answer (score 1):

See below if this is what you want

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("textarea[name='order[header_comments]']").on('keyup', function(e) {
    var keynum;

    if (window.event) { // IE                    
      keynum = e.keyCode;
    } else if (e.which) { // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                   
      keynum = e.which;
    }
    //console.log(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
    let headerVal = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
    $("textarea[name*='line_comments']").each(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).val() + headerVal);
    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="order[header_comments]" placeholder="header box"></textarea>

<textarea name="line_comments[0][line_comments]"></textarea>
<textarea name="line_comments[1][line_comments]">some existing text</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks that is a good start.  That will be having issues though with keeping the header text immutable.  Also, updating header text does not keep the line boxes in sync with the "header text first", "original text second".  I think I need to find a way to maybe only display the header text in the line box but not having it actually editable.  I'm not sure, maybe instead of putting int into the box, make it look like it is in the box, or maybe print it right before the box (although that will be less desirable, but still work essentially)

Comment: so if i understand you correctly you want to prepend the newly entered text to the line comments text ?

Comment: yes... and if possible make it unmodifiable (header text that is in line boxes should be non-modifiable).  This may need a different approach

Comment: hmm... that might get tricky as the approach I have used adds/appends a single character every time on key up and if we try to pre-pend it, the resulting text in the line comments would be the reverse of what we are actually typing in. means if i type `OMER` it will be appended as `REMO`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[order[header_comments]]').change(function(){
var headText = $(this).val() ;
    $("textarea[name*='line_comments']").each(function() {
      $(this).val(headText + ' ' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```